# Why does my program not print the IF function?

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

This is a practice question from CS50 whereby the user should input 3 dimensions. If the sum of the lengths of two sides are greater than the length of third side, it should print the valid  text, if not, print the invalid text in main.

```
//validate whether the user's input dimensions can make a triangle
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool valid_triangle(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void)
{

//ask user for input
    float a = get_float("Enter the length for one side of a triangle: ");
    float b = get_float("Enter the length for the second side of a triangle: ");
    float c = get_float("Enter the length for the third side of a triangle: ");

//if valid input
    if (valid_triangle(a, b, c))
    {
        printf("Well done. The dimensions %.2f, %.2f, and %.2f make a triangle!\n", a, b, c);
    }

//if invalid input
    else
    {
        printf("Please try again. These dimensions do not make a triangle.\n");
    }
}

//check user input
bool valid_triangle(float a, float b, float c)
{
    if ((a <= 0) || (b <= 0) || (c <= 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (b + c <= a))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My program seems to be stuck printing only the invalid response and I can't narrow down why. My `debug50` tool doesn't work so I tried breaking this down myself by swapping the second `return false;` in the bool function out for `printf("DEBUG");`. This actually worked and resulted in the program printing my valid response in the main function. I don't know why though and caveat was that it would *only* print the valid response. I feel like the program is at 98% but there is something small in the way of it getting to 100%.

Comment: What values for `a`, `b` & `c` are you testing with?

Comment: When I enter 3 4 and 5 it responds "Well done...."

Comment: Your algorithm seems correct to me for various hard-coded values. https://godbolt.org/z/PxKGh8hGo What does `check50` say when you run your program using it?

Comment: Please [edit] and show some examples of input along with expected vs. actual output.

Comment: Try printing the values of the variables right after the `get_float` functions. Then try commenting out the calls to `get_float` and calling `valid_triangle` with hard-coded values, like `if (valid_triangle(3, 4, 5))` and see what happens. This will make it faster to run it. And add some more `printf` to the `valid_triangle` function, one for each return statement, just above it, like `printf("One side is negative");` and `printf("One side is too long");`

Comment: And when I enter 1 2 and 4 it responds with "Please try again...."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`I don't know why though and caveat was that it would only print the valid response.` seeing this line I think there is a comprehension problem. The program shouldn't always print the successful answer (correctly) but only for some values. E.G. as others have stated in the comments `1 1 1` should `return true` but `1 1 3` should `return false`. I suspect you are using values that are correctly returning `false` but you are expecting them to return `true`.

`swapping the second return false; in the bool function out for printf("DEBUG");. This actually worked and resulted in the program printing my valid response in the main function.`
means that you are not using values that are `0` or `negative` so that removes that potential issue in your inputs.

If the triangle can be also made with a line "overshooting" the others like this:

```
\
 \
 |\
 | \
 |  \
 |___\
```

you need to change your `||` to `&&` inside `((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (b + c <= a))` but then the program will ALWAYS `return true` for positive non-zero numbers (like you are saying) but I don't really think that's what the practice question was asking you to do.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. It seems as though it works exactly as it is meant to today. This may sound impossible but yesterday it simply would not work. Perhaps i was tired and putting the numbers in the wrong way around. All of your explanations were great and useful nonetheless. Apologies for the redundant question.